# ROS2 Topic on WSL Can not Find All Available Topics

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ros, ubuntu-20.04, ros2

I have a ROS2 Galactic version installed in my `Ubuntu 20.04` inside **WSL** on my **Windows 11**. I have a `Turtlebot4` which is functioning without issues. My windows pc is connected to the same network as the TurtleBot4 but whenever I ran `ros2 topic list` topics published by my TurtleBot is not showing up. I can see only two topics:

```
/parameter_events
/rosout
```

I checked the following issues as well:

> 1. Both my PC and the TurtleBot are connected to the same wifi network.
> 2. I can ssh into the Turtlebot4 RPI without errors so it's working fine.
> 3. I tried connecting to the bot with a PC comes with Ubuntu as default OS. It works fine there. Unfortunately, changing my default OS (Windows) is not an option for now.

Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Comment: could it be the [`ROS_DOMAIN_ID`](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-CLI-Tools/Configuring-ROS2-Environment.html) being different? Try going through all the environment variables related to ROS

Comment: I tried `echo ROS_DOMAIN_ID` on rpi but it did not return anything.